# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - WiFi not shown and no ethernet port available

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I've tried to solve a problem using some solution found online but there is no way to start wifi (I think that the driver is not found). Any idea how to solve?

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 22 Feb 2018 20:50 CET +0100

Booted last: 22 Feb 2018 00:00 CET +0100

Script from: 10 Jan 2018 20:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.13.0-36-generic #40~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 16 23:25:58 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:0110]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:58d2 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13fe:3d00 Kingston Technology Company Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

iwlwifi               249856  0
cfg80211              614400  1 iwlwifi
asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    24576  4 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  40960  3 asus_wmi,nouveau,i915

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2276 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2276 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:168656 (168.6 KB)  TX bytes:168656 (168.6 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

##### resolv.conf #######################

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       822     1  0 20:43 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Rome (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.13.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-33.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-33.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0--33.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-a0-jf-a0--33.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-jf-b0--33.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-jf-a0--33.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-jf-b0--33.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-hr-a0--33.ucode
srcversion:     339D7D3BD0DD2A9C7FE616F
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       4.13.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
parm:           d0i3_timeout:Timeout to D0i3 entry when idle (ms) (uint)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.13.0-36-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     A5EDD7467E172A70410EBCD
depends:        
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.13.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
d0i3_timeout: 1000
disable_11ac: N
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: 3

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    3.235286] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.239519] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-33.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.239539] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-32.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.239548] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-31.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.239557] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-30.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.239565] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-29.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.239575] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-28.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.239584] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-27.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.239594] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-26.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.239603] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-25.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.239612] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-24.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.239621] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-23.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.239629] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.239631] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
[    3.239634] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: minimum version required: iwlwifi-8000C-22
[    3.239636] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-8000C-33
[    3.239638] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
[    4.578780] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a driver but you lack firmware. On some other computer, please download this package onto a flash drive: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.169.3_all.deb

Drag and drop the package from the flash drive to your Ubuntu desktop. Then open a terminal and do:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg  -i linux-firmware*.deb
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Is your wireless working now? It may take a reboot.

Comment: Can you explain where do you find this information in that log?

Comment: It is in your wireless info above: "iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: no suitable firmware found!" You can also confirm it from the terminal: `dmesg | grep iwl`

Answer (score -2):

if you have wired internet connection the just go to the SOFTWARE & UPDATE and click ADDITIONAL DRIVERS from there you can easily install or enable your wireless.
it worked for me.

Comment: OP is missing firmware files as is clearly visible from the kernel error messages. -1