# Are windows and ubuntu wireless firmware the same?

Tags: wireless, windows, kubuntu, intel

I have a dualboot Windows 8.1 and Kubuntu 17.10 with Intel Wireless 7260 - Rev 6b.

My internet is very unstable and unreliable, and after researching the problem i suspect it's the firmware. Installing firmware through Ubuntu seems a little complex and open to me messing things up.

So if I installed the firmware through windows, would this mean that I wouldn't need to install it for Ubuntu?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the latest firmware is actually quite easy. It is the same as this: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - WiFi not shown and no ethernet port available](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008835/ubuntu-16-04-lts-wifi-not-shown-and-no-ethernet-port-available/1008855#1008855)

Having said that, I doubt that your issue is firmware. I own and use successfully two Intel wireless devices, including a 7260. I have honed a few techniques in several years and thousands of forum posts.

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

I suggest that you also disable power saving in Network Manager. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Any improvement?

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, your suggestions made a great improvement to my connection, so it looks like it wasn't the firmware then!

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour